# FAB on collapsing toolbar not showing icon when changed after behaviour hide

Tags: android, kotlin, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, floating-action-button

I have a FAB anchored to collapsing toolbar so when the toolbar collapses the FAB get hidden, when i click the FAB the icon toggles correctly, but after i scroll and the FAB get hidden when i try to change icon it dissapears, but when i collapse and expand the toolbar the icon shows correctly, also i tried invalidating

I have tried change icon with resource and drawable, but i get the same result

Here's a GIF with the problem:
https://media.giphy.com/media/1zKOxmWQ8IIpFgtvPM/giphy.gif

This is what i have right now:

```
fun setFABState(isFav: Boolean, isSeeing: Boolean = false) {
    launch(UI) {
        fab.setImageDrawable(when {
            isFav && isSeeing -> drawableStarHeart
            isSeeing -> drawableHalfStar
            isFav -> drawableHeartFull
            else -> drawableHeartEmpty
        })
        fab.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: Well, some really basic stuff, setImageResource() and setImageDrawable()

Comment: Have you finally found solution for this issue?

Comment: @user3400881 yes, i updated to latest material library

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I could see is may be it is ending up in else -> drawableHeartEmpty . Please debug and see if both the flags (isFav,isSeeing) are false .

Comment: Yes, all the logic there works fine, when the activity opens it changes normally, with any of the 4 icons

Answer (score 0):

Try to pull branching statement out of method parameters. I have some kind of problem before with `if-else` statement.

```
fun setFABState(isFav: Boolean, isSeeing: Boolean = false) {
    launch(UI) {
        val icon = when {
            isFav && isSeeing -> drawableStarHeart
            isSeeing -> drawableHalfStar
            isFav -> drawableHeartFull
            else -> drawableHeartEmpty
        } 
        fab.setImageDrawable(icon)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, same problem